# An image become large in size when it is shared

Tags: swift, uiimage, image-resizing, autofilter

I am taking an image by device camera and add an autoAdjustmentFilters. Then I compress it's size and save to document directory. Now problem is when I am sharing this image by airdrop, image becomes larger in size. I am facing this problem when I am sharing the image in JPEG format but not in PDF format. Related code is given below:

```
let aCGImage = inputImage.CGImage;
self.aCIImage = CIImage(CGImage: aCGImage!)
let Filters = self.aCIImage.autoAdjustmentFilters() as [CIFilter]
  for Filter in Filters {
           Filter.setValue(self.aCIImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
           self.outputImage = Filter.outputImage!
            }
   let CgImage = self.context.createCGImage(self.outputImage, fromRect: self.outputImage.extent)

      self.newUIImage = UIImage(CGImage: CgImage!)




     let mydata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.newUIImage, 0.5)
     print(">>>>>>>>>>>>,,,,,,,,,\((mydata?.length)! / 1024) kb")
```

Then I save this image data in document directory. When I save this image in document directory, it's size is 600kb-1500kb, but after sharing it's size is larger than 10000kb. Don't understand what the problem is.